# IIS7.5 - Self Signed Certificate doesn't work when mapped

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I have followed [these](http://ondrej.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/iis-7-and-client-certificates) instructions to restrict access to my site to only users that I issue a certificate to, the server runs Windows 2008 R2 and IIS7.5.

The process of creating a self signed CA and user certificates signed by that CA worked no problem, then I installed my CA into trusted authorities and restarted the server.
I have a real SSL certificate from GoDaddy assigned to my site so I didn't have to issue a self signed website certificate for that purpose.

Now the issue...
I tried both manual editing using IIS Configuration Editor and [this extension](https://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-09-85-62-31/ClientCertificateMapping.zip).

The problem is, when I map the user certificate (base 64 version) on IIS and try to browse the site I always get 401 after picking the certificate from the browser popup no matter what user name and password I put under the client certificate mapping, if I remove the certificate from the client certificate mapping the 401 error is gone and the page loads fine, as long as I don't map the certificate that I select on the browser popup the page loads fine.

The event log error when I map the client certificate is "Unknown user name or bad password.", 4625, without mapping the client certificate the page loads ok if I select the certificate but doesn't generate any event log like "success", if I don't pick the certificate it shows 403 Forbidden.

If I turn off anonymous authentication then it won't work either way, mapped or not mapped, some sites say anonymous is required by client certificate, others not.

I don't need to setup a Windows user on the web server for each certificate, right?

Why is the website loading successfully when I don't map the client certificate?

Any idea why my setup is not working when I actually map the certificate?

Comment: here's the output from certutil:

SimpleChain.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
SimpleChain.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN (0x40)